# select for update twice to same table by diffrenet key cause deadlock in MySQL

Tags: mysql, deadlock

- Table foo has id and name.
- Transaction A select for update by id 1.
- Transaction B select for update by id 1 then wait.
- Transaction A select for update by name anything(even though not exists) cause Transaction B deadlock.

Why this happen ?

Below scripts reproduce deadlock.

```
create table foo (id int primary key, name varchar(100));
insert into foo values (1, 'foo1');

-- transaction A
start transaction;
select * from foo where id=1 for update;

-- transaction B
start transaction;
select * from foo where id=1 for update;
-- now waiting

-- transaction A
select * from foo where name='xxxxx' for update;
-- transaction B dead lock occer
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out close answer.

MySQL locks all records when select for update searched by no indexed column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html

> If you have no indexes suitable for your statement and MySQL must scan the entire table to process the statement, every row of the table becomes locked, which in turn blocks all inserts by other users to the table.

But, I don't know why this causes deadlock.

By the way, I resolved my problem that every select for update to search by primary key.